# How to make a star where the user has input to how many points the star has?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to make a turtle function where the user can directly control the size and how many points the star has, but I'm lost. Could someone help me out?

The code that I have now does odd pointed stars ok, but it completely messes up on even numbered points.

```
import turtle
import math

def draw_Star():
    X = int(input("Star;Select X-Coordinate here: "))
    Y = int(input("Star;Select Y-Coordinate here: "))
    turtle_color3 = input("Star;Color of Turtle: ")
    points = int(input("Star;Enter num of points: "))
    size = int(input("Star;Enter size of star: "))

    star = turtle.Turtle()
    star.speed(1)
    star.color(turtle_color3)
    star.penup()
    star.goto(X, Y)
    star.pendown()
    s = points

    angle = (360/s)

    for i in range(0,s):
        star.right(angle*2)
        star.forward(size)

draw_Star() 
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Try drawing a 6-sided star. You'll notice that it's made of two triangles, and you have to lift your pen to stop one triangle and start the next

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41335401/5771269) about drawing odd and even stars using coprimes to help with drawing and detect stars that can't be drawn using a continuous motion.

Answer (score 0):

Notice what is happening here if you calculate the value for the formula `(360/sides)*2`

```
Sides: 2 Angle 360.0
Sides: 3 Angle 240.0
Sides: 4 Angle 180.0
Sides: 5 Angle 144.0
Sides: 6 Angle 120.0
Sides: 7 Angle 102.85
Sides: 8 Angle 90.0
Sides: 9 Angle 80.0
Sides: 10 Angle 72.0
Sides: 11 Angle 65.45
Sides: 12 Angle 60.0
Sides: 13 Angle 55.38
Sides: 14 Angle 51.42
Sides: 15 Angle 48.0
```

Your formula works for odd values and not even values, because the even values are just retracing the polygon that would be produced by `((360/sides)*2)/2`

In fact the only difference between this program and a program that will produce a polygon of `n` sides is the multiplication of the angle by `2`

While I don't know the limits of python turtle, which is similar to logo.

To draw stars with even numbers of sides, the best method would be to use trigonometry and radians to find points and then calculate the location of that star point relative to your positions.

That may be more complicated than you are looking at but try changing `star.right(angle*2)` to `star.right(angle)` and you will see it will make any polygon you want.

That 2 in `star.right(angle*2)` tells you it won't work for even numbers of sides.  So you will need to find a more advanced algorithm to accomplish that task.

While I haven't told you how to do that task I hope you have an understanding why this current program only works for odd numbers of points.